# Querying for colorControlHighlight value at runtime returns negative value

Tags: android, styles, android-theme, android-styles, ripple

I'm trying to get the color of a ripple in runtime:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        ...
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:theme="@style/ripple_theme"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/og_close_icon_a11y"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/quantum_gm_ic_close_vd_theme_24"
        tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout"/>
```

values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="ripple_theme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/google_yellow100</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Plus do I need to set the alpha to be 10% or is this the value set by the ripple automatically?

I have tried to retrieve android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight color value at runtime, but I always get a negative value.

How can I fix this?

```
int result = 0;
View closeBtn = findViewById(R.id.close_button);
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();

Resources.Theme theme = closeBtn.getContext().getTheme();
boolean wasResolved =
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight, outValue, true);
if (wasResolved) {
  result =
      outValue.resourceId == 0
          ? outValue.data
          : ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), outValue.resourceId);
}
result = result + 0;
```

Comment: Negative value does not mean it's an error. Colors use 32 byte integer with 8 bytes per color (argb) which causes alpha values higher than 127 to "overshoot" into first byte which is normally used as a sign byte.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I get the color code to check on any decima to hex -to color website?